# How to cast from double to int in from_json Spark SQL (NULL output)

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with a JSON string

When running this Spark SQL query:

```
select from_json('[{"column_1":"hola", "some_number":1.0}]', 'array<struct<column_1:string,some_number:int>>')
```

I get a `NULL`, since the data types for `some_number` are not matching (`int` vs `double`)...

If I run this it works:

```
select from_json('[{"column_1":"hola", "some_number":1.0}]', 'array<struct<column_1:string,some_number:double>>')
```

Is there a way to CAST this on-the-fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do **`from_json`** first using **`array<struct<column_1:string,some_number:double>>`** then `cast` as 
 **`array<struct<column_1:string,some_number:int>>`**

**`Example:`**

```
spark.sql("""select cast(from_json('[{"column_1":"hola", "some_number":1.0}]', 'array<struct<column_1:string,some_number:double>>') as array<struct<column_1:string,some_number:int>>)""").show()

//+-------------------------------------------------------+
//|jsontostructs([{"column_1":"hola", "some_number":1.0}])|
//+-------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                            [[hola, 1]]|
//+-------------------------------------------------------+

//printSchema
spark.sql("""select cast(from_json('[{"column_1":"hola", "some_number":1.0}]', 'array<struct<column_1:string,some_number:double>>') as array<struct<column_1:string,some_number:int>>)""").printSchema()

//root
// |-- jsontostructs([{"column_1":"hola", "some_number":1.0}]): array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |-- column_1: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- some_number: integer (nullable = true)
```